# Storing and Retrieving image path in database mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am developing a website using PHP, mysql and phpmyadmin. I have some database that I what want to retrieve it in html using PHP and mysql. I want to know how I can store and retrieve image paths from database and display it. I saw on the internet that there is a way, such as using the filesystem to store and retrieve images or making my laptop a server.
what is the best way and how?
I would be grateful for any help, Thanks.

Comment: upload all files to a particular folder. in database, just store the image name. while fetching, you will know what is the path, just add image name to fetch and display it.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: I know that storing and retrieving image as blob is not efficient, I want  better way , for big database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since, you didn't described your question properly or didn't provided any code.
So, i assumed your question in my way and posted my answer.
Follow the step.

***1) For Uploading Image***

```
<form method='POST' action='UploadImage.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='UploadImage'>
    <input type='submit' value="submit">
</form>
```

Suppose your Project Folder Name Is : MyProject (Where all project files are present),
Make one folder inside "MyProject" Folder namely "MyUploadImages"
Now,

**UploadImage.php**

```
<?php
include('connect.php'); // Do Database Connection in this file (create a file namely connect.php inside MyProject Folder)
extract($_POST);

$UploadedFileName=$_FILES['UploadImage']['name'];
if($UploadedFileName!='')
{
  $upload_directory = "MyUploadImages/"; //This is the folder which you created just now
  $TargetPath=time().$UploadedFileName;
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory.$TargetPath)){    
    $QueryInsertFile="INSERT INTO TableName SET ImageColumnName='$TargetPath'"; 
    // Write Mysql Query Here to insert this $QueryInsertFile   .                   
  }
}
?>
```

Now, In your Database Table, you can find ImageColumnName that image path is set as MyUploadImages/1417Flower.jpg

***2) Retreiving Image from database***

**AnyPage.php**

```
<?
$Query="SELECT * FROM TableName";
// Write mysql query to fetch $Query

store that ImageColumnName value to any variable say $MyPhoto.
?>

<img src="<?echo $MyPhoto;?>">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually my real problem is in retrieving the image because i have a simple search engine using php, and I'm storing the result in a variable to show as an html, like that in index.php :       $result "<div class='content '><h2>$title</h2><img src='<?php echo $image; ?>'  class='content' /></div>";   It seems that php is not working because it displays crached pictures. although the title is retrieved .

Comment: crached pictures means @Judy ??

Answer (score 2):

> *or making my laptop a server* >> I dont get that... do you have a server and php, and mysql server ?

As said Nirajan, the good way to do that is to store the path in DB, and the file itself in the folder you want. You will then use the field with the path to display your image :

```
for $image in $imagesList // *pseudo code*
    <img src="$image->getPath()">
endfor
```

A quick search on the web will help you to find out the "real code" to do that !

Comment: my problem was that image src doesn't accept anything but a string, but your code makes sense, Thank you

Comment: you just have to store a string ;) like /serverRoot/myProject/images/image.png

Comment: No, i want to retrieve an image from database, and not like that, because it might change

Comment: you have to give more informations ... or to read a few tutorials abot PHP and MySQL