# Uploading image into MySQL from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

As title I am trying to upload images on a DB Mysql using PHP:
Here are the scripts: (I know I should use mysqli...)

form in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="AlterVista - Editor HTML"/>
  <title> Carica un'immagine </title>
</head>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000">
  Invia questo elemento: <input name="userfile" type="file"></br>
  <input type="submit" value="Carica">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
    //Connect to DB
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'realegr', 'pass', 'my_realegr');
    if (!$conn){
        die("Could Not Connect to MySQL!");
    }
    if(!mysql_select_db("my_realegr")){
        die("Could Not Open Database:" . mysql_error());
    }
    //file properties
    $file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

    if (!isset($file)){
      echo "<p>Please Select an Image</p>";
    } else {
      $image = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));
      $image_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
      $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

      if ($image_size==FALSE) {
        echo "<p>NOT AN IMAGE</p>";
      } else {
        echo "<p>File is an Image. Processing...</p>";
        if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (name, image) VALUES ('$image_name','$image')")){
          echo ("<p>Error Uploading Image: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
        } else {
          $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
          echo "<p>Success!</p>";
          echo "<img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
        }
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Obviously there is another php script (get.php),but the problem is in this one.
The error I got is this:
File is an Image. Processing...

> Error Uploading Image: Data too long for column 'image' at row 1

I can't understand the reason...(the image is of just 70 kb)

(THis is my table:
id int primary key Auto_increment
name varchar(50)
image blob
)

Comment: Check [Storing and Retrieving image path in database mysql php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086311/storing-and-retrieving-image-path-in-database-mysql-php/33088086#33088086)

Comment: use `LONGBLOB` instead of `BLOB` for your `image` column in table

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR: But, That's is not a good practice to have it so. Better, we can store image/file in one directory and just save the path in database column.

Comment: `$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'realegr', 'pass', 'my_realegr');` this has failed, outright. That doesn't use 4 arguments, but 3.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Do you mean save the images in a directory of web server?Why it would be better?

Comment: @Nana yes you are right, but that is a different way to storing the images. Here problem came by MySQL due to column size

Comment: Because storing and retrieving BLOBs is very intensive @Nick9214. Indexing is difficult and it makes the database work overtime.

Comment: Ok so I will try in that way too..Anyway @RAUSHANKUMAR was right...with longblob now it works

Answer (score 1):

Don't save image data in the database. There is no need, and could even cause your site to run more slowly!

Instead, save it into an uploads folder that isn't publicly accessible using `move_uploaded_file()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Once you do that, store the **path** to the file in the DB!

Comment: "Sorry but the path is this $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']??". Yes, until you use `move_uploaded_file()`, then it becomes a normal file path like `/var/www/site/data/uploads/photo.jpg`, or whatever. Store that in a `varchar` column!

Answer (score -3):

Currently you have this line:`"INSERT INTO images (name, image) VALUES ('$image_name','$image')"`. What if you attempted to change it into something like:

```
<?php
    // NOTICE THE "LOAD_FILE"
    // WHERE $fileToLoad IS THE PATH TO THE UPLOADED IMAGE-FILE 
    "INSERT INTO images (name, image) 
    VALUES('$image_name', LOAD_FILE({$fileToLoad}))";
```

However, storing images in the Database, from experience, is always not the very best of options...consider storing the images in a dedicated folder and simply saving only the address in your Database....

Comment: Sorry but the path is this $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']??

Comment: You missed the fact the OP is using `mysql_connect()` improperly.