# Uploading file and displaying the uploaded file

Tags: php, html, file

I'm trying to upload a file to my php server then display the image to the user. But it doesn't seem to work. The file destination that I print out with seems correct `echo($fileDestination);`.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" size="35" type="file">
                <br>
                    <br>
                        <input name="upload" type="submit" value="Upload">
                        </input>
                    </br>
                </br>
            </input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

php

```
<?php 
    $file=$_FILES['fileToUpload'];
    $fileName=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

    $fileDestination='uploads/'.$fileName;
    move_uploaded_file($fileName, $fileDestination);
    echo($fileDestination);
    echo "<img src='" . $fileDestination . "'>";
?>
```

Edit: Updated php file

```
<?php 
    $file=$_FILES['fileToUpload'];
    $fileName=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

    $tmp_name=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $filename=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

    $dest='C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\2.2.2 Fil uppladning\images'.$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest);
    echo($dest);
    echo "<img src'" . $dest . "'>";

    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest);

    if(!$result){
        var_dump(error_get_last());
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to use tmp_name rather than name.

Comment: Check [Storing and Retrieving image path in database mysql php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086311/storing-and-retrieving-image-path-in-database-mysql-php/33088086#33088086)

Comment: I currently don't want a database

Comment: @FigFiggins check my answer that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using **relative path** to move file use **full path**
And give `tmp_name` on source

```
$tmp_name=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$filename=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

$dest=dirname(__FILE__) . '/uploads/' . $filename;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest);
```

And to find the exact error do this

```
$result = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest);

if(!$result){
    var_dump(error_get_last());
}
```

Note: **uploads** folder must exist. `move_uploaded_file` cannot create dir itself

to display image

```
 echo "<img src='images/". $filename . "'/>";
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I get these warnings: [ImageOfWarnings](https://i.gyazo.com/aaf4d9fd3b394e76fc0443b9718b3dd9.png)

Comment: replace this path `/full/path/to/your/project/uploads/` with your own project working dir

Comment: The updated answer doesnt work but Changing path to my path solved the warnings but didnt actually display the image. Could the ´echo´ command be wrong? 
The echo($dest) = 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\2.2.2 Fil uppladning\images22218141_1660540297331142_2086972872_o.jpgNULL`

Comment: Update your current code now. Let me check. Seems something wrong with your dest path and make sure your destination folder is exist

Comment: @FigFiggins checked your code change your path to `C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/2.2.2 Fil uppladning/images/`

Comment: And confirm that your images uploaded to images folder

Comment: What returns null? `<img` tag?

Comment: ACtually no, the if statement var_dump(error_get_Last()); returns null. I don't think the img tag is correctly formatted?

Comment: to display image you need to use http or https protocal

Comment: what you mean? Surley I can just use an echo img src to display an image?

Comment: Yes, check my answer I have updated. Now you can use relative image location to display the image. the browser automatically maps the whole path of your image

Comment: oh ye it worked! But is there a way to create the folder instead of having a static dest adress?

Comment: what do you mean by static dest address? If answer worked please upvote or mark it as answer it so it will helpful for others

Comment: If I run this program another pc without this directory it won't work. also the path will be wrong

Comment: Yes. you can do like this `$dest=dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/' . $filename;` . It refers the current working dir

Comment: Thanks for the help! I solved the static thingie. Thanks again! I can't upvote but I can mark as answer!

Comment: Glad to help you, Happy coding <3

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
    move_uploaded_file($fileName, $fileDestination);
```

To this

```
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $fileDestination);
```

Comment: I get the following error `No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\2.2.2 Fil uppladning\test.php on line 8`

Comment: At loading image time? <img src"dir"> ?

Comment: I don't understand your question @Ajay Korat

Comment: $filename=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']; Fully error list I linked down under Thamaraselvam's answer as a link

Comment: Please share output of print_r($_FILES);

Comment: Everything is correct @AjayKorat except his path. check his error tmp file is created

Comment: The path is correct now, I've changed it to my fully path on my pc, warnings are gonne but the image won't display